# Converting to a decimal without rounding

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a float number, say `1.2999`, that when put into a `Convert.ToDecimal` returns `1.3`. The reason I want to convert the number to a decimal is for precision when adding and subtracting, not for rounding up. I know for sure that the decimal type can hold that number, since it can hold numbers bigger than a float can.

Why is it rounding the number up? Is there anyway to stop it from rounding?

Edit: I don't know why mine is rounding and yours is not, here is my exact code:

```
decNum += Convert.ToDecimal((9 * 0.03F) + 0);
```

I am really confused now. When I go into the debugger and see the output of the `(9 * 0.03F) + 0` part, it shows `0.269999981` as float, but then it converts it into 0.27 decimal. I know however that 3% of 9 is 0.27. So does that mean that the original calculation is incorrect, and the convert is simply fixing it?

Damn I hate numbers so much lol!

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Agreed. It does not round up on my machine.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(1.2999));` prints `1.2999`.

Comment: Remember .9 repeating = 1.

Comment: I tried it in my console app, code is:                            float value = 1.2999f;            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(value));
Console.ReadLine();    OUTPUT:1.2999

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you say is happening doesn't appear to happen.

This program:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float f = 1.2999f;
            Console.WriteLine(f);
            Decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(f);
            Console.WriteLine(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
1.2999
1.2999
```

I think you might be having problems when you convert the value to a string.

Alternatively, as ByteBlast notes below, perhaps you gave us the wrong test data.

Using `float f = 1.2999999999f;` *does* print `1.3`

The reason for that is the float value is not precise enough to represent `1.299999999f` exactly. That particular value ends up being rounded to `1.3` - but note that it is the *float* value that is being rounded *before* it is converted to the decimal.

If you use a `double` instead of a `float`, this doesn't happen unless you go to even more digits of precision (when you reach `1.299999999999999`)

[EDIT] **Based on your revised question, I think it's just expected rounding errors, so definitely read the following:**

See ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for details.

[Also see this link](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) (recommended by Tim Schmelter in comments below).

Another thing to be aware of is that the debugger might display numbers to a different level of precision than the default `double.ToString()` (or equivalent) so that can lead to you seeing slightly different numbers.

---

Aside:

You might have some luck with the "round trip" format specifier:

```
 Console.WriteLine(1.299999999999999.ToString());
 Prints 1.3
```

But:

```
Console.WriteLine(1.299999999999999.ToString("r"));
Prints 1.2999999999999989
```

(Note that sneaky little 8 at the penultimate digit!)

For ultimate precision you can use [the `Decimal` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as you are already doing. That's optimised for base-10 numbers and provides a great many more digits of precision.

However, be aware that it's hundreds of times slower than `float` or `double` and that it can also suffer from rounding errors, albeit much less.

Comment: I think he just screwed up his test data. Try `1.2999999999f;`

Comment: @ByteBlast: With `1.2999999999f`, you don't even need `ToDecimal`: `Console.WriteLine(1.2999999999f);` prints `1.3`. I don't think `float` has enough precision for this number.

Comment: Same here, I got the exact output

Comment: @ByteBlast: You are probably correct; I'll add a comment to my answer.

Comment: Well float has [precision limit of 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: This link is also worth reading: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware that `Decimal` is a lot slower but I also read that it is the "only" type one should use when precision is required. Floats tend to screw up with adding or subtracting for some reason.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper That advices generally applies to currency calculations. Other calculations, such as positioning pixels on the screen or calculating scientific results (vectors, velocities etc) can use doubles. Significantly, you can't use trigonometric, logarithmic or square root or power methods with Decimal.